# SQL Select Top n percent rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a rather difficult query.
I need to write a query on a table called 'key_phrases' (columns: 'user', 'phrase', 'tfw') which retrieves the top 10% rows for each user, that have the highest values of column 'tfw'. THe query should return all columns.
thanks in advance, Nil

Comment: What datapye contains the column 'ftw'? What exactly is the meaning of this column? Are any example values available?

Comment: values of ftw (float) :  0.00473934 ,
0.00173913

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select user, phrase, tfw
from key_phrases t1
join (
    select count(*) total_rows_per_user, user
    from key_phrases
    group by user
) t2 on t1.user = t2.user
where (
    select count(*) from key_phrases t3
    where t3.user = t1.user
    and t3.tfw >= t1.tfw
) / total_rows_per_user <= .1
```

another query using variables which should be faster

```
select user, phrase, tfw,
if(@prev_user = user, @user_count := @user_count + 1, @user_count := 1),
@prev_user := user
from key_phrases t1
join (
    select count(*) total_rows_per_user, user
    from key_phrases
    group by user
) t2 on t1.user = t2.user
cross join (select @user_count := 1, @prev_user := null) t3
where @user_count / total_rows_per_user >= .9
order by user, tfw
```